# Why the double language of "all his creations that he created"

Tags: blessing, bentching, language

The first blessing of [birkat hamazon](https://www.tefillos.com/birkas_hamazon.asp) concludes with the statement that God prepares sustenance for "all of his creations that he created". What is the explanation for this double, redundant sounding language?

Comment: For any down voters, please consider leaving an explanation. I would be happy to adjust the question as necessary.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But, I don't think this is redundant. I think it's more emphasis and "acknowledgement" of who the creator is. Also, the term *briyah* can also mean "living things". Thus, the full end of the sentence could mean "...all living things that you created."

Comment: Great question just something in support: The
Darchei Moshe Hakatzar in O"C siman 187 says: ובהגהת סמ"ק מצאתי דאין לומר לכל בריותיו אשר ברא דמשמע מינה דאיכא נמי בריות שלא ברא ואיכא כפירה אלא יש לומר לכל הבריות ואין המנהג כן אלא אומרים לכל בריותיו אשר ברא:

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.lookstein.org/lessonplans/bh/bh_text.pdf), [here](http://xn----1hckee1axk8eva.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/K4A_Birkat_Hamazon.pdf) and [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Siddur_Ashkenazi/Blessings/Birkat_Hamazon) . all translate בְּרִיּוֹתָיו אֲשֶׁר בָרָּא as "creatures whom God (or he) has created".

The point is that I don't think the phrase is redundant, but rather, a form of acknowledgement, here. I.e., we know that there are creatures and many living things, but we are acknowledging that G-d has created them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answers the question. Had the sentence ended with all his creation (briotav) would I not have been able to deduce that God created them?

Comment: @rikitikitembo YOU probably would. But there are heretics, skeptics, etc. According to Gemarra (I guess in Brachot?) Moshe composed this first blessing. If that's true, there were already various non-believers and skeptics brewing among *Bnei Yisra'el*. Perhaps, this was to affirm the idea. Also, see user15469's comment. I'm unfamiliar with his source, but I've tagged him to add that info, as I think it may add to my answer, here.

Comment: l'hefech! As per the gemarah you cited (48b) since this is a b'racha d'oraita that Moshe wrote I would assume each word is carefully measured and extraneous words, even if they could possibly deter a heretic, would be avoided.

Comment: That's a fair argument. I'm not certain I completely agree with you, but, it certainly is something to consider. Regardless, as I explained, I don't think the wording is redundant, esp. if we consider that the first word is translated as "creatures". Note, also, that the spelling is without an *aleph*, which MIGHT suggest that it's not from the same *shoresh* as *barah*. I'm uncertain about that. Can another MY'er confirm / dispute?

Comment: @riki it says Moshe established it not that he wrote it. seems pretty unlikely that he wrote a blessing containing a verse from Psalms...

Comment: @DoubleAA i agree he didn't write the language as we have it today but surely you concede that he was involved in the original writing, correct?

Comment: @rikitikitembo I concede it likely he was involved with some of the initial recommended formulations. But only because at the time people likely would have asked him (as a prophet and the leader of the Jewish people) for ideas, not because initial formulations are a necessary component of establishing.

Answer (score 1):

Meir Friedman in [Beis Talmud vol. 5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48112&st=&pgnum=330&hilite=) (page 354), after discussing variant versions which either leave out "which He created" or add "which He created in His mercy and in his Great kindness" (ברחמיו וברוב חסידיו) or leave out the whole phrase, gives two possible explanations:

1) He prepares for every species that he created the sustenance which is most appropriate and best for it.

2) Because he created them he provides all their needs.